# Windows Laptop Keyboard Alt+Tab Issue

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I have a Windows laptop that has been with me for 5+ years now. It's perfectly fine and couple of months ago I even upgraded the NVMe and did a clean Windows installation as well. After that also it's been working fine. All of a sudden yesterday I get this weird issue with the laptops built in keyboard. Whenever I hit `Alt+Tab` to switch between opened windows the keyboard starts acting weird. It won't switch windows. Instead it will act as only the Alt key was pressed. For example if you go into Chrome and press Alt key you will see the three dots at the top right corner gets highlighted. That's what happens when I try to `Alt+Tab`. Also when `Alt+Tab` was pressed sometimes the other keys of the keyboard won't work except the Windows key. Meaning I can't type anything but I can open the Start menu using the Windows key. For the other keys to work again I will have to restart the laptop. Sometimes when `Alt+Tab` is pressed it will act like only the Tab key was pressed. Both Alt and Tab keys work individually. All these issues come when I hit them both in order to switch windows.

**Things I have tried. (None of them fixed the issue)**

- Restarted.
- Run the Windows troubleshooter for the keyboard.
- Restart windows explorer from task manager (this was something came up when I googled the issue)
- Checked for any windows updates.

I tried plugging in an external keyboard and it works all right. I can Alt+Tab using that. So the issue is within the built in keyboard of the laptop. Is this a hardware issue? Will i have to replace the keyboard? or can this somehow be software related even though the external keyboard works fine?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you test other keyboard shortcut combinations to see if they work? For example, perform a copy and paste, CTRL+C to copy, and CTRL+V to paste. The point of this step is to see if your keyboard has any issues reading multiple inputs pressed synchronously. Also, historically, pressing Alt by itself selects the first option in the menu bar. The arrow keys should work to select different options in the menu bar. Pressing Alt again once should return control, assuming there isn't some other weird problem.

Comment: @JimDiroffII I tried CTRL+C and CTRL+V. They work fine. No issues with them. Speaking about your second point. When I hit Alt+Tab it selects the first option of the menu bar.

Comment: Slightly improbable here, but have you perhaps turned on "sticky keys" by mistake?

Comment: @SaaranshGarg Nope. I have it turned off.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Sometimes, a failing battery expands, pushing against the keyboard. You might check if loosening the back of the case allows the keyboard to work, and, if so, check the battery.